# When override a method, say(), and then run the program I do not get what I anticipated to be printed

Tags: java

I have a superclass pet with the following code:

```
package pet;

public class pet {
int age;
float weight;
float height;
String color;

public void sleep(){
    System.out.println(
                "Good night, see you tomorrow");
}

public void eat(){
    System.out.println(
    "I'm so hungry...let me have a snack like nachos");
}

public String say(String aWord){
    String petResponse = "OK!! OK!! " + aWord;
        return petResponse;
    }
}
```

I created subclass to pet, Fish:

```
package pet;

public class Fish extends pet {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fish myLittleFish = new Fish();
    myLittleFish.sleep();
    }

public String say(String something) {
    return "Don't you know fish do not talk?";
    }               

}
```

Then I created another class FishMaster:

```
package pet;

public class FishMaster {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Fish myFish = new Fish();

    myFish.say("Hello");
   }

}
```

When I run FishMaster it does not output: Don't you know fish do not talk?
It does not output anything.

Why is that? What do I need to put to make it output: Don't you know fish do not talk?

This is a lesson from a book, Java Programming for Kids, Parents and Grandparents, that I found the link to from another question.

Answer (score 5):

`say` returns a String but you dont display it

```
System.out.println(myFish.say("Hello"));
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you aren't printing anything, you are just returning a `String`.

Try changing your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Fish myFish = new Fish();
   System.out.println(myFish.say("Hello"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `myFish.say("Hello")` should be enclosed in `System.out.println()` `myFish.say()` is simply returning a `String`, but doing nothing with it.  You need to print whatever is returned by `say()`

Answer (score 0):

**What do I need to put to make it output: Don't you know fish do not talk?** 
 make your say() method like this

```
   public void say() {
     System.out.println("Don't you know fish do not talk?");
 }
```

and call it this way

```
  Fish myFish = new Fish();

  myFish.say();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your say() method currently only returns a string, you will need to either print the returned string
or include a print in your say() method.